# How to convert bitmap file into picture file with Android

Tags: android, xml, bitmap

I wanna read a file full of bmp resource and show it on my android app. But know idea how to do this, I put my file under resets folder.
The file looks like this 
`<image id="labelThumbnail" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="data:image/bmp;base64,Qk24KwAAAAAAACAAAAAMAAAAwwNaAAEAAQD///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABg/////+8R////37///4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert base 64 string to Bitmap like this.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the base64 to bitmap like this:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedBase64Value, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

You can also resize it using this:

```
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedByte, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create a file to write bitmap data
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), yourFilename);
file.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
Bitmap bitmap = Your bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//Write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bitmapdata);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```